# Javascript executes function immediately when passing arguments, undesired

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, execute, args

When I run the code:

```
 $(".pro-tip-1").mouseover(activateProTip(1));
```

It calls the function activateProTip right away. It doesn't wait for the mouseover to be a true scenario.

Now if I take out the argument (1) being passed, it runs as intended. It waits for mouseover to be true then it calls the function. This is what I want, however I also want to pass an argument.

```
 $(".pro-tip-1").mouseover(activateProTip);
```

The problem is I can't seem to pass an argument and have it run as intended, but I want to be able to pass an argument.

I am completely new to Javascript if that isn't already obvious so please keep your code in response simple to follow, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected, the required argument is a function. If you instead pass a statement, it will be interpreted immediately (potentially you could have called a function which actually returns a function that you want to call on mouseover!). You can instead write a function that will then call `activateProTip` with the argument.

```
$(".pro-tip-1").mouseover(() => activateProTip(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution it will work

```
$(".pro-tip-1").mouseover(()=>activateProTip(1));
```

Explanation:
you can use always callback function for click events.

when you calling like this(activateProTip(1)), this will not binding events, that's why it will call the immediatly